# Transcription by RNA polymerase in absence of inducer and activator

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, transcription

Does the presence of activator(CAP-cAMP complex) and inducer(lactose) only increase the likelihood that a particular gene(here operon) gets transcribed, i.e increases the rate of transcription of that gene?And transcription of some(assumption) genes always happen?

Because as I know basal level transcription is something that happens always,even without an inducer.

Comment: Some genes have basal transcriptional activity whereas some may not at all. Are you asking whether all genes have some basal activity in the absence of an activator?

Comment: @WYSIWYG No. I'm asking what is the role of inducer and activator for e.g in lac operon. Do they solely increase the rate of transcription of the operon increases? Is it same for all genes (It mustn't be because you said that not all genes have basal level transcription)? For some set of genes then transcription factors (activators) and inducers solely switch on the gene.